# PouchDB/CouchDB like alternative for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, couchdb, pouchdb, nosql

I'm amazed by the sync capabilities of Pouch and Couch DB, but I'm looking for for an alternative that will let me use my MongoDB databases for client-sync. Is there such thing?

If there is, I'd like to hear your experience with it, what should I be aware of, if there are any catches, etc...

Comment: After searcing Goolge for "Client Sync" https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ouchdb+client+sync&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=3DR8VP22JvOq8wfWwIHQDw#rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&channel=fflb&q=couchdb+client+sync I am not exactly sure what you mean. Can you put your question into terms that we would understand? Maybe explain your position and what you want

Comment: @Sammaye PouchDB is a client-side library that syncs with CouchDB on the server-side. I'm looking for something similar for my client-size app, but for MongoDB on the server-side.

Comment: Minimongo is what your looking for: https://github.com/mWater/minimongo

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using PouchDB with MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24384803/using-pouchdb-with-mongodb)

Answer (score 2):

[Minimongo](https://www.meteor.com/mini-databases) is specifically what you are looking for.  It was originally developed as part of the excellent Meteor framework, but it can now be used independently to get the local db store and synchronization with a remote db, all using Mongo api.