# Ionic framework app work offline and syncing data with mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, ionic-framework, synchronization, offline, pouchdb

I am developing an app in ionic framework and using MongoDB as database. I want to work my app on offline and sync the data to my database. I find PouchDB which works as a local storage and sync with CouchDB. But I also find, [there is no way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24384803/using-pouchdb-with-mongodb) to sync PouchDB with MongoDB. Is there any other local storage which work offline and sync with MongoDB?

Answer (score 1):

The best alternative I'm aware of is minimongo: https://github.com/mWater/minimongo

Comment: There is no stable version in minimongo. So its really risky to go with it. One more thing, is there any way to sync PouchDB with MongoDB?

Comment: No, sorry: http://pouchdb.com/faq.html#sync_non_couchdb. PouchDB is really one of the best sync solutions out there, and a big reason is because we chose CouchDB instead of MongoDB. :) MongoDB is good at many things, but CouchDB is far superior in its sync capabilities.

Comment: Hello Nlawson, is there any way to use Pouchdb with Angula2?

Comment: Sure, check out [this tutorial](http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-use-pouchdb-sqlite-for-local-storage-in-ionic-2/).