# Nodejs Web Application Runs Offline

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb

I have developed an Web Application on Node.js with MongoDb 
I come across an issue that my end users have limited or sometimes no internet connection available.
So, is there any way to Start Web Application using internet and Load on Laptop or Mobile Browser. Once load it works and save data on Mobile Device or Laptop and once Connected to Internet then the data sink to Server.

http://pharmevo-phq9.herokuapp.com/
login: abc
password: 12345

Actually, this is Medical Camp Web Application. The End User is my Company Medical Representative. There is Internet Connection Issue within Doctor Clinic. So, there is issue in using within Doctor Clinic.
Is there any way that, our Representative Login to Application and load it outside Clinic and then go within clinic (offline) and use it. All Data Save within Laptop or Mobile Device. Once, he come out of Clinic and connected to internet then all data sink to Server.

Please guide me.
Best Regards.

Comment: You need a database that syncs like this [one](https://pouchdb.com).

Comment: Is MongoDb Syncs like this? Or I need to Use any other Database?

Comment: Is there any easy way to Shift my Database MongoDb to PouchDB?

Comment: No easy way according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24384803/using-pouchdb-with-mongodb) question.

Comment: Is there any way if I convert Nodejs Application to Android App to Run Offline?